# Is it possible to parse with JSONObject and RealmObject with the same model?

Tags: android, json, realm, android-json

I don't want to create separate models for json and realm. I'm looking for a way to do that.

How do I handle this in a single model without creating two models?

My Json;

```
"story": {
   "id": 3,
   "title": "title",
   "is_new": false,
   "thumbnail": "url",
   "original": "url",
}
```

MyRealmObject

```
public class stories extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Required
    private String id;
    @Required
    private String title;
    private boolean isNew;
    @Required
    private String thumbnail;
    @Required
    private String original;

    [..and getter setter..]
}
```

Comment: Yes it is completely possible to use the same model for both Json Parsing and as RealmObject

Comment: This is usually a bad decision. You want your local data to be separated from the data you receive from a server. Btw, yes, just use `@SerialzedName()` by `GSon` or Moshi adapter to convert a Json to your `RealmObject`

Comment: @p.mathew13 Can you provide me a sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same model for both JSON parsing and for Realm.

you may need to use `SerializedName` because field `is_new` won't work.

example:

```
public class Stories extend RealmObject {


private int id;
private String title;

@SerializedName("is_new") // required
private Boolean isNew;// use preferred name

private String thumbnail;
private String original;

/* getter & setter */

}
```

> Parsing

```
Stories mDataClass = new Gson().fromJson("{/*whatever your json object*/}", Stories.class);
```